# Javascript call function as string, with multiple parameters not using eval()

Tags: javascript

I am quite new to javascript, but I know you can call a function with it being represented by a string such that:

```
 var function_to_call = window[values['function']];
 //Where values['function']='functionName'
```

So far so good, then we have:

```
 if(typeof function_to_call == 'function'){
       if(values['parameters']!= '')
                function_to_call(values['parameters']);
       else function_to_call();
  };
```

Of course, this won´t work because the parameters come out as "parameter1, parameter2" all in one string so you end up with

```
function_to_call("parameter1, parameter2");
```

rather than

```
function_to_call(parameter1, parameter2);
```

any ideas? Appreciate your time!

**EXPANDED:**

The parameters passed to the function represent the "id" of elements in the page; so the function that is called will be trying to get those elements by doing:

```
document.getElementById(parameter1);
...some other things...
document.getElementById(parameter2);
```

Comment: What data type is `values['parameters']`?

Comment: You probably need to parse the parameters string into parameter array first and then use function.apply() to call the function.

Comment: @Paul, a string such as: 'parameter1, parameter2'.

Comment: @bigbearzhu I´ll look into function.apply() since I don´t know what it is.

Comment: Got it woking with .apply(), thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the parameter names represent global variables as well.

If so, you could split them into an Array, then `.map()` the Array into a new array of the related globals.

Then use `.apply()` to invoke the function with the array of arguments.

```
if (typeof function_to_call == 'function') {
     if(values['parameters']!= '') {
          var args = values['parameters'].split(",")
                                         .map(function(name) {
                                             return window[name.trim()];
                                         });
          function_to_call.apply(window, args);
     } else function_to_call();
}
```

The `.trim()` and `.map()` methods will need a shim for IE8... but this mainly shows how you could do it. As an alternative, you could pass a regex to `.split()` to take care of any spaces.

```
var args = values['parameters'].split(/\s*,\s*/)...
```

Comment: `'   param, param2   '.trim().split(/,\s*/)` is `["param", "param2"]`,  saves you a loop. But what happens if you have a param that looks like `"\"hello, world\""`?

Comment: @PaulS.: Yes, but I think OP wants to resolve them to global variables. If not, then yes, the loop isn't needed.

Comment: @PaulS.: Those wouldn't be valid variables. They're valid properties when enclosed in a string, but I'm pretty sure OP is after variables here.

Comment: @CrazyTrain What exactly does "I assume the parameter names represent global variables as well." mean?I apologize but I am newbie with javascript, and I believe that that phrase is important because your example is not giving me the result I need.

Comment: @Joy: You're getting your `function_to_call` by using the string value of `values['function']` to access it from the `window` object. This works because all global variables are accessible from that object. So I'm assuming that you're wanting to do the same with `"parameter1"` and `"parameter2"`, meaning that they are strings that are meant to be used as the names of global variables, just like with your function. Is that the case? If not, then what are those `parameter` values meant to represent?

Comment: @CrazyTrain I'll edit the post to clarify it for everyone else too! (thanks for the explanation!)

Comment: @CrazyTrain I used .apply(), and parsed the string to array with .split(",") , and made sure that the parameters passed employed no spaces and only comma-separation so as to avoid .map() (to trim white spaces). thanks for the help!

Comment: @Joy: So you got it working? I can't tell if that's what you're saying. If the comma-separated values are the acutal IDs, and names of not variables that hold the IDs, then you should be able to do `function_to_call.apply(window, values['parameters'].split(","))`

Comment: @CrazyTrain That is exaclty what I did! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(typeof function_to_call == 'function'){
   if(values['parameters']!= '')
            setTimeout('function_to_call('.values['parameters'].');');
   else  setTimeout('function_to_call();',0);
  }
```

Comment: Using `setTimeout` like this is an `eval`.